# Nesting multiple context manager functions of an object

Tags: python-2.7, with-statement, contextmanager

I am using python 2.7(migration not complete yet) and trying to build an aggregate class(Cluster) which provides the same context manager function(reserved) as on its individual items(Node). I would ideally like to do this without refactoring the context manager function of the contained object Node. If it had separate enter() and exit() methods, perhaps I would have directly called them in the Cluster.reserved() context manager function. But I thought there might be more elegant ways of doing it. I tried following code with ExitStack:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from contextlib2 import ExitStack

class Node:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id

    @contextmanager
    def reserved(self):
        print("Node {} reserved".format(self._id))
        try:
            yield
        except:
            print("Exception while handling node")
        finally:
            print("Node released")

    def reserve(self):
        print("Node {} reserved".format(self._id))

    def release(self):
            print("Node {} released".format(self._id))

class Cluster:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id
        self._nodes = [Node(1), Node(2), Node(3), Node(4)]

    @contextmanager
    def reserved(self):
        with ExitStack() as cm:
            cm.enter_context(node.reserved() for node in self._nodes)
            print("Cluster {} reserved".format(self._id))
            try:
                yield
            except:
                print("Exception while handling cluster")
            finally:
                print("Cluster released")
    @contextmanager
    def reserved2(self):
        with ExitStack() as cm:
            for node in self._nodes:
                reserve = node.reserve()
                cm.callback(node.release(), reserve)

            print("Cluster {} reserved".format(self._id))
            try:
                yield
            except:
                print("Exception while handling cluster")
            finally:
                print("Cluster released")

node = Node(10)
with node.reserved():
    print('Node {} handled'.format(node._id))


cluster = Cluster(10)
with cluster.reserved2():
    print('Cluster {} handled'.format(cluster._id))
```

The first function reserved() returns

```
AttributeError: type object 'generator' has no attribute '__exit__'
```

while the second one doesn't really yield after reserving all the nodes. Wondering what is the right way to handle this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cm.enter_context(node.reserved() for node in self._nodes)
```

That code wasn't right. I should have used the list comprehension properly to pass the contextmanager object properly to enter_context